# Sorting on a Column Defined as String in HIve

Tags: sql, hive

I have created a table in Hive, where I have defined Order_id field as String. But it has Integer values.

Now when I run the following SQL, I get incorrect results.

```
select * from orders_string2 Order by order_id limit 10;

1   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   11599   CLOSED
10  2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   5648    PENDING_PAYMENT
100 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   12131   PROCESSING
1000    2013-07-30 00:00:00.0   2321    CLOSED
10000   2013-09-25 00:00:00.0   8983    PROCESSING
10001   2013-09-25 00:00:00.0   316 PENDING_PAYMENT
10002   2013-09-25 00:00:00.0   1530    COMPLETE
10003   2013-09-25 00:00:00.0   8099    COMPLETE
10004   2013-09-25 00:00:00.0   7768    CLOSED
10005   2013-09-25 00:00:00.0   541 COMPLETE
```

Following SQL gives correct results:

```
select * from orders_string2 order by int(order_id) limit 10;

1   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   11599   CLOSED
2   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   256 PENDING_PAYMENT
3   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   12111   COMPLETE
4   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   8827    CLOSED
5   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   11318   COMPLETE
6   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   7130    COMPLETE
7   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   4530    COMPLETE
8   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   2911    PROCESSING
9   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   5657    PENDING_PAYMENT
10  2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   5648    PENDING_PAYMENT
```

Now when I ran following SQL, i expected an incorrect result. But it worked fine.

```
select * from orders_string2 where order_id > 100 limit 10;

101 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   5116    CLOSED
102 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   8027    COMPLETE
103 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   12256   PROCESSING
104 2013-07-25 00:00:00.0   7790    PENDING_PAYMENT
105 2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   8220    COMPLETE
106 2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   395 PROCESSING
107 2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   1845    COMPLETE
108 2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   12149   PROCESSING
109 2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   9345    PENDING_PAYMENT
110 2013-07-26 00:00:00.0   2746    COMPLETE
```

This one also works fine and does not need casting.
select count(*) from orders_string2 where order_id > 100
68783

Can someone plz shed light on this? Why WHERE and SORT BY clause are working differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL strings are sorted alphabetically.  Hence, "1", "10", and "100" all come before "2", in the same way that "a", "ab", and "abc" all come before "b".  That explains the first two queries.

When you run this query:

```
select *
from orders_string2
where order_id > 100 
limit 10;
```

You have no `order by`.  Any 10 records can be returned that match the `where` condition.  You are "lucky" that they are the ones you expect.

If you add `order by order_id` then you will get a different set, basec on the data in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much. This helps.